# How can electron diffraction be described using the Schrödinger equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, diffraction

Can someone point me to resources where this process is described using the Schrödinger equation? It's not obvious to me how that could be done, as you'd need to define the proper potential.

Comment: Are you specifically asking for the whole process of electron going through the slit? Or just treating the slit as multiple sources?

Comment: @BioPhysicist About the whole process.

Comment: AFAIK this cannot be done, as you say because one would have to define a potential and solve with the S equation, Instead, the plane wave wavefunctions of the S equations (or of other quantum mechanical wave equations) are used to define the e=scatterin matrix https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-matrix for the given boundary conditions/problem

Comment: @annav Where can I read more about this? Can you point me to a textbook?

Comment: @agaminon if you even glanced at the reference in wikipidia you will see that it  needs a course in quantum mechanics and then field theory methods.It is not simple ,.